# unable to create new ec2 instance after initial creation

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk

I have the following code:

```
 $result = $ec2->runInstances(array(
          // ImageId is required
          'ImageId' => $image,
          // MinCount is required
          'MinCount' => 1,
          // MaxCount is required
          'MaxCount' => 1,
          'KeyName' => $key,
          'SecurityGroupIds' => array($sg),
          'InstanceType' => $type,
          'Placement' => array(
              'AvailabilityZone' => $az,
          ),
          'Monitoring' => array(
              // Enabled is required
              'Enabled' => false,
          ),
          'SubnetId' => $subnet,
          'PrivateIpAddress' => $ip,
          'ClientToken' => 'string',
          'AdditionalInfo' => 'string',
      ));
      $instanceIds = $result->getPath('Instances/*/InstanceId');
      $ec2->waitUntilInstanceRunning(array(
          'InstanceIds' => $instanceIds,
      ));
```

this worked with no issues the first time I ran it. after initial run I terminated the instance from  the EC2 console. now I am getting the following error every time I try to create a **new instance**.

`A resource entered into an invalid state of "terminated" while waiting with the "InstanceRunning" waiter.`

I do not understand why the waiter is looking at the old instance ID , is this somehow persisting?

Is there something else I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. it was an error on my part. I was setting the  `'ClientToken' => 'string'` which in turn would always try to query the previously created instance becuase 'string' was the unique id.